# docker swarm - Performance Bottle Neck

Tags: web-services, docker, tomcat8, docker-swarm

While doing Performance testing in Docker Swarm cluster, the Transactions Per Second(TPS) is not going beyond 400 TPS and the response time is gradually increasing.
While doing Performance testing on one server the TPS is around 200.
So with 10 nodes cluster, it should atleast go beyond 1500 TPS.
But the TPS is not going beyond 400. It seems the Leader is not able to handle more than 400 requests and distribute to the other 9 nodes in the cluster.

Any information on this will be really helpful.Is there any configurations that needs to be done in the Swarm cluster, that will increase the TPS

The docker swarm details are provided below:

1. Docker version: 1.12.1

Swarm Structure: - Leader(Manager):server1 - Other Managers: server2 and server3 - Workers: All other 7 servers/nodes

2. Application/Service endpoint:

http://server1:8080/Application/Service The above endpoint has been shared with our clients, so act as the load balancing endpoint.

3. The application is a webservice deployed in Tomcat 8 using docker.
4. Swarm Cluster

```html
ID                           HOSTNAME      STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
0415czstge3vibxh55kwnywyd    server6  Ready   Active
2keplduit5vaycpwzv9419gh7    server4  Ready   Active
2r5e2ye9jhgko29s5bv7rolxq    server3  Ready   Active        Reachable
5btrbs5qkrlr50uiip6n0y260    server9  Ready   Active
7aqpnf79tv7aj1j5gqsmqph7x    server10  Ready   Active
856fyn6rdv9ypfz8o2jdsuj7p    server2  Ready   Active        Reachable
a1gcuucxuuupg9gleu9miz7uk    server5  Ready   Active
a2uyjjhh7phm3wei2e1ydsc4o    server7  Ready   Active
bm7ztqyrbt7noak6lerfmcs3j *  server1  Ready   Active        Leader
dwto8iizy8li46b7u6v9e4qk1    server8  Ready   Active
```

Comment: Your version of Docker is horrifically old. Please update and let us know how it goes :)

Comment: What version are you suggesting John?As am afraid we cannot just go and upgrade, as this version is being used by other services also.

Comment: 1.12.1 was released on Aug 18, 2016. The commercially-supported version of 1.12.x (if you're on that) was EOL in late 2017. If you're on OSS Docker, that version is long past not receiving any updates, patches, security fixes etc... In short, I would advise developing a plan to move to a more up-to-date version pretty soon. I would suggest the latest stable release which is 18.03.x right now.